# R - Change colnames of dataframe created by 'assign' function

Tags: r

I have the code as below.

```
i=1
RCF_Per <- *some code*       
assign(paste('RCF', i, sep='_'), RCF_Per)
assign(paste('df_RCF', i, sep='_'), data.frame(get(paste('RCF', i, sep='_'))))
colnames(get(paste('df_RCF', i, sep='_'))) <- "ABC"

--> Error in colnames(get(paste("df_RCF", i, sep = "_"))) <- "ABC" : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

How can I change the colname of that df?

Answer (score 0):

I assume ,if you are to just rename a column name a better way could be to use *dplyr*

```
 RCF_Per %>% rename(ABC = df_RCF)
```